# Serializing multiple std::shared_ptr via boost::serialization and sending over boost::asio

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-serialization

I'd like to transmit a `shared_ptr` object via boost asio from a client to a server. Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Message {
public:
    Message() {
    }

    virtual ~Message() {
    }

    string text;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar &text;
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Message)

void runClient() {
    // Give server time to startup
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("localhost", "3000");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(stream);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::shared_ptr<Message> dl = std::make_shared<Message>();
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Hello " << i;
        dl->text = ss.str();
        archive << dl;
    }

    stream.close();
    cout << "Client shutdown" << endl;
}

void handleIncommingClientConnection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor &acceptor) {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;

    acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());

    boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(stream);

    while (true) {
        std::shared_ptr<Message> m;

        try {
            archive >> m;
            cout << m->text << endl;
        } catch (std::exception &ex) {
            cout << ex.what() << endl;

            if (stream.eof()) {
                cout << "eof" << endl;
                stream.close();
                cout << "Server: shutdown client handling..." << endl;
                break;
            } else
                throw ex;
        }
    }
}

void runServer() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 3000);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, endpoint);

    handleIncommingClientConnection(acceptor);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    thread clientThread(runClient);
    thread serverThread(runServer);

    clientThread.join();
    serverThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 3
Hello 3
Hello 3
Hello 3
Client shutdown
Hello 3
Hello 3
input stream error
eof
Server: shutdown client handling...
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4
Hello 5
Hello 6
Hello 7
Client shutdown
Hello 8
Hello 9
input stream error
eof
Server: shutdown client handling...
```

When changing the `shared_ptr` to a simple object (`std::shared_ptr<Message> m;` to `Message m`) everything works as expected. I want to stick to the `shared_ptr`. What do I need to change?

Serialization alone seems to work:

```
stringstream stream;

{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(stream);
    std::shared_ptr<Message> dl = std::make_shared<Message>();
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hello World!";
    dl->text = ss.str();
    archive << dl;
}

{
    boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(stream);
    std::shared_ptr<Message> m;
    archive >> m;
    cout << m->text << endl;
}
```

Output: `Hello World!`

Comment: The problem is that you destroy the old message and create a new one on each iteration. As it happens in your case, after the 4th iteration, the new message object is allocated at the same address -- in my test on coliru this happened for all the message objects. You can easily validate this yourself by printing the value of `dl.get()`.

Comment: Now, why is this an issue? The raw pointer is how the serialization framework can tell whether two shared pointers point to the same object. (Inspect the contents of the archive). Basically, there's a requirement that all the shared pointers point to some objects prior to the whole serialization sequence, and are not modified during the sequence (or at the least anything you already serialized shouldn't be changed, and unique object needs to have unique addresses).

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111041/boost-serialization-multiple-objects

Comment: There you go. Do peruse the docs, they were quite elucidating. I haven't used this particular library much before, definitely not in this context, and digging for the references to write the answer confirmed my conclusions from experiments I based the comments on. Thanks for a useful question :)

Comment: You should probably ask yourself why you're faking that you're serializing shared-objects, while fact you are not. This is the source of the bug.

Comment: @sehe My real codebase uses shared_ptr and I am not able to change it. I just tried to come up with a minimal example that reproduces the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues you're encountering are due to [object tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking) done by [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/).

> Depending on how the class is used and other factors, serialized
>   objects may be tracked by memory address. This prevents the same
>   object from being written to or read from an archive multiple times.
>   These stored addresses can also be used to delete objects created
>   during a loading process that has been interrupted by throwing of an
>   exception.

The documentation actually foreshadows this specific issue happening:

> This could cause problems in progams[sic] where the copies of different
>   objects are saved from the same address.

Furthermore, the [Class Serialization Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#tracking) documentation on object tracking tells us that in this particular situation, object tracking is enabled:

> Default tracking traits are:
>
> - For primitive, track_never.
> - For pointers, track_never. That is, addresses of addresses are not tracked by default.
> - All current serialization wrappers such as boost::serialization::nvp, track_never.
> - For all other types, track_selectively. That is addresses of serialized objects are tracked if and only if one or more of the
>     following is true:
>
>   - an object of this type is anywhere in the program serialized through a pointer.
>   - **the class is explicitly "exported"** - see below.
>   - the class is explicitly "registered" in the archive

---

Going back to your situation -- in the client, due to how your loop body is written, the 5th (and following) `Message` instance were allocated at the same address as the 4th `Message` instance. You can verify this by inspecting the values of `dl.get()` in each iteration. (In my tests on coliru, all of the instances were allocated at the same address, so YMMV).

Due to how object tracking works, all those `shared_ptr` instances were considered to point to the same `Message` instance (even though you changed the value meanwhile -- the library does not expect this happening), so the additional occurrences were just serialized as additional references. Upon deserialization... to be honest this smells of memory leaks and/or dangling reference issues (opinion, haven't investigated this in detail).

Summed up, the main issue with the code as shown is that it breaks a prerequisite of the serialization library, which is that you're serializing some constant state, and on deserialization you recreate that same state.

One way to address this would be to have an initialized `std::vector` of `shared_ptr<Message>` containing all the messages to transmit in this particular transaction. Similarly, you'd deserialize the whole vector on the other side. If you expect to have some persistent connection, then add framing to the protocol, with each frame containing an archive that contains one sequence of messages.

---

Minimal code modifications to make this work -- add include

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

Change `runClient()` as such:

```
void runClient() {
    // Give server time to startup
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("127.0.0.1", "3000");

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Message>> messages;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::shared_ptr<Message> dl = std::make_shared<Message>();
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Hello " << i;
        dl->text = ss.str();
        messages.emplace_back(dl);
    }

    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(stream);
    archive << messages;

    stream.close();
    cout << "Client shutdown" << endl;
}
```

And change `handleIncommingClientConnection(...)` as such:

```
void handleIncommingClientConnection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor &acceptor) {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;

    acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());

    boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(stream);

    while (true) {
        try {
            std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Message>> messages;
            archive >> messages;
            for (auto const& m : messages) {
                cout << m->text << endl;
            }
        } catch (std::exception &ex) {
            cout << ex.what() << endl;

            if (stream.eof()) {
                cout << "eof" << endl;
                stream.close();
                cout << "Server: shutdown client handling..." << endl;
                break;
            } else
                throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

*NB*: This doesn't add any support for multiple frames -- the client is expected to close the connection after it sent one vector of messages, otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

<kbd>[Sample on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b02f46aadda45cda)</kbd>

---

Further resources:

- [boost serialization multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111041/boost-serialization-multiple-objects)